# Xcos - Include an xcos model inside another?

Tags: scilab, xcos

Is it possible to place one xcos model inside another?

I'm working on a motor control simulation.  I would like to put together a script which plots open and closed loop responses.  The most straightforward way to do this is to put the motor model in one superblock used for the open loop simulation, then make a copy of that superblock for the closed loop simulation.  Unfortunately, that means any time I change the motor model, I have to change both copies (or copy the block again, which breaks the connections).

Ideally, I would like to have the motor model to live in a "motor.zcos" file and be able to place two instances of it in a main.zcos file.  Changing motor.zcos would naturally affect both instances.

Is there any way to do this?  Or is there another recommended way of solving the problem?

[Scilab 6.1.1, Windows 10]

Answer (score -1):

You may have a single diagram for both simulations just opening the feed back loop removing a link

Comment: The idea is running both models simultaneously.  Also, this is a specific example of a more general problem - there are lots of reasons you might want 2 copies of the same sub block running in a model